# How to split a data file into several sections

Tags: c++, io, split, fwrite

I have a file with some data in it, and I am trying to split it up into several files. Seeing the data file will help you understand.

```
#AFlags: -O0

    #Bytes  blowfish       AES      3DES
       1MB        60        20       280
       5MB       320        90      1400
      10MB       570       180      2720
      20MB       560       180      2740
#BFlags: -O1

    #Bytes  blowfish       AES      3DES
       1MB        60        20       280
       5MB       300       100      1440
      10MB       600       170      2680
      20MB       550       170      2790
```

This is what it looks like. I am trying to read this file in, then split it at each line at the `#[letter]Flags`. So far this is what I am doing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    string line_contents, initial_cpp_time_data, compare, find, file_path, file = "";
    ofstream time_data_file;

    //Grab the data from the old file
    ifstream initial_cpp_time_data_file ( "cpp_time_data.txt" );
    if (initial_cpp_time_data_file.is_open()) {
        while ( getline( initial_cpp_time_data_file, line_contents ) ) {

            compare = line_contents.substr(2,5);
            if ( strcmp( compare.c_str(), "Flags" ) == 0  ){
                file_path = "results_files/" + line_contents.substr(1,5) + "_result_data.dat";
                cout << "file_path: " << file_path << endl;

                time_data_file.open( file_path.c_str() );
                time_data_file << file << endl;

                time_data_file.close();
            }
            cout << "line_contents: " << line_contents << endl;
                file = file + line_contents;
                file.push_back('\n');


        }
        initial_cpp_time_data_file.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Unable to open the data file" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Done with format data!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I feel like I almost have it, but there is something wrong with my logic. It is creating two files, `AFlag_result_data` and `BFlag_result_data`. `AFlag_result_data` is empty, and `BFlag_result_data` has the data I want `AFlag_result_data` to have in it. How to I separate the data into the correct file. Also, I could have varying amounts of lines, so I cannot hard code it to split each 6 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the first line containing `Flags`, `file_content` is empty. That's why there's nothing in the first file and the content that should be in the first file shows up in the second file.

The following tweaked version of `main` works for me:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    string line_contents, initial_cpp_time_data, compare, find, file_path, file = "";
    ofstream time_data_file;

    //Grab the data from the old file
    ifstream initial_cpp_time_data_file ( "cpp_time_data.txt" );
    if (initial_cpp_time_data_file.is_open()) {
        while ( getline( initial_cpp_time_data_file, line_contents ) ) {

            compare = line_contents.substr(2,5);
            if ( strcmp( compare.c_str(), "Flags" ) == 0  ){
                file_path = line_contents.substr(1,5) + "_result_data.dat";
                cout << "file_path: " << file_path << endl;

                if ( time_data_file.is_open() )
                {
                   time_data_file.close();
                }
                time_data_file.open( file_path.c_str() );
            }
            cout << "line_contents: " << line_contents << endl;
            time_data_file << line_contents << std::endl;
        }
        if ( time_data_file.is_open() )
        {
           time_data_file.close();
        }
        initial_cpp_time_data_file.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Unable to open the data file" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Done with format data!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

To deal with empty lines, change the line

```
compare = line_contents.substr(2,5);
```

to

```
if ( line_contents.size() >= 5 )
{
   compare = line_contents.substr(2,5);
}
else
{
   compare.clear();
}
```

Comment: It works! I tried the file path tweak, but I didn't know how to check if it was open. Thanks

Comment: @R Sahu What if there was an empty line after each '#Flags:' line? I can't do substr because it is out of bounds.

Comment: @R Sahu You really helped me out!